# can't build for adhoc distribution appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, ad-hoc-distribution

I`m having lots of trouble with this one. I tried compiling an app for adhoc distribution and started with this error:

> Failed to export archive to ipa
>   [ERROR] :  The selected provisioning profile "" is most likely not a valid Ad Hoc provisioning profile.
>   [ERROR] :  Please ensure you are using a valid Ad Hoc provisioning that is linked to the signing identity, then try again.

I "solved that part" running `appc run -p ios -T dist-adhoc`through console line, but then I got

> Cannot find module '/Users/ggomez22/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/MODI-Express-Dashboard/undefined'
>   [ERROR] Alloy compiler failed

also solved that one running `sudo npm install alloy -g` which also resulted in an error related to my defaultIcon.png (solved that) but now I'm stuck with

> Session invalid. Please log in again.

I already tried logging in and out several times but the problem persists, I also tried with `appc logout -D` and had to use the code sent to my email to log in again but that didn't solve the problem either.

I need help with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to download Appc Studio & setup everything there. It looks like you are trying things piece by piece. Solve one & move to other problem. so it's better to avoid this tedious process & use Appc Studio IDE to build your project.

It's merely of 400MB & everything should be working fine.

Studio can also report you errors if there are any other because you can't be sure what's stopping you from building app from command line.

Looking at that **Session Invalid** issue, I used to solve it using **appc login** without logout as it refreshes the tokens & necessary things.

Comment: I was using appcelerator studio, that is where I found the first error, then I was suggested to run in console to find the command appcelerator uses, and then I found the next errors. I ended downloading my repository again to go back to the first more simple problem.